How does GCP Logs Router handle conflicting rules?
I created separate Log routing sinks to capture specific logs for various services being used. All of these sinks wrote to the same dataset.
For example, the various inclusion filters looked similar to:

jsonPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dataform.logging.v1.WorkflowInvocationCompletionLogEntry") <-- capture dataform execution results
resource.type="cloud_run_revision" AND logName=("projects/<project_name>/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr" OR "projects/<project_name>/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstdout") <-- capture cloud run stdout and stderr outputs
NOT protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail : "gserviceaccount.com" <-- capture all logs that aren't service accounts.

Because these were all being written to the same dataset, I assume google handles de-duplication if there is overlap in the records (is this true?)
However I also wasn't able to find certain logs (particularly from service accounts) that I think my 3rd route sink was excluding.
My general question is, If you have overlapping/conflicting logs being routed to the same dataset, what is the expected behavior?

I recognize that it is probably best to remove route rout sink rule #3 above, and just condense all of these into a single routing sink to capture ALL logs. But I would still like to understand expected behavior for future projects.

Hi scott C ,It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case . Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.
